# How to use the return value of a java method in an XML

Tags: java, xml, junit, automation

I have an xml like this

```
<step>
                <navigationButtonSelector>.step-one-action-button</navigationButtonSelector>
                <formField>
                    <name>emailAddress</name>
                    <value>new2@gmail.com</value>
                </formField>
</step>
```

Now I can't hardcode the value (new2@gmail.com) here. Instead I have to randomly generate a string and use it whenever I am running my automation suite. Can I generate a random string at runtime within the xml itself.

The other possibility is to create a Java method which returns a random String. Now how could I use that value in my XML file? Please help

Comment: Generate the string and then generate the XML file.  There seems to be no reason why the XML file needs to exist before the string is generated.  Or if the file is complicated, code a placeholder value with some easy-to-recognize syntax ("%%%ADDRESS GOES HERE%%%") and then write a method to replace the placeholder.

Comment: How is your Java code reading and processing the XML?

Comment: If you have just one variable, you could save yourself from parsing and just perform the transformation. While not as powerful for other situations it may improve code readability and runtime performance. In this case you need to create a suitable stylesheet (XSL-T) and run the transformer with a variable set to your random string.

Answer (score 0):

This code may look bloated but actually is very powerful in case you have to perform more editing. It shows the whole roundtrip from parsing, modifying and serializing the XML data from and to String.

```
String xml = "<step>\n" +
    "                <navigationButtonSelector>.step-one-action-button</navigationButtonSelector>\n" +
    "                <formField>\n" +
    "                    <name>emailAddress</name>\n" +
    "                    <value>new2@gmail.com</value>\n" +
    "                </formField>\n" +
    "</step>";

// parse document
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
    
// find editing locatioin
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
Element value = (Element)xpath.evaluate("/step/formField/value", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
    
// replace value
while (value.hasChildNodes()) {
    value.removeChild(value.getFirstChild());
}
value.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("a random string"));

// serialize document
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newDefaultInstance().newTransformer();
t.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(sw));
xml = sw.toString();

System.out.println(xml);
```